# Convert XML structure into a Pandas DataFrame without using a complex set of for loops

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I'm trying to convert XML into a pandas dataframe. I tried a method from Austin Taylor website but without success.

Here's my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml_data = open("C:\\Users\\John__000\\Documents\\Analytics\\ANLT Data Wrangling\\Assignments Viz\/xdemo_stat.xml").read()

def xml2df(xml_data):
root = ET.XML(xml_data) # element tree
all_records = []
for i, child in enumerate(root):
    record = {}
    for subchild in child:
        record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
        all_records.append(record)
return pd.DataFrame(all_records)
```

After running that code, nothing happened. I'm expecting a dataframe but it didn't work. What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you call the function? Here you only define it. And please post XML for us to reproduce.

Comment: Yes I did call it, but I got an error saying ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 50

Comment: As mentioned, please post XML for us to reproduce. We can't help otherwise.